# Why I am getting can not read proprty play of undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Doctor Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script>

        window.onload = function callButtonClickEvent() {
            setTimeout(function () { playSound(); }, 2000);

        };

        $( document ).ready(function() {
             $('#source')[0].play();
        });


        function playSound() {
            document.title = "(1) Doctor Page"
            var filename = "eventually";
            var mp3Source = '<source src="' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">';
            var oggSource = '<source src="' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg">';
            var embedSource = '<embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="' + filename + '.mp3">';
            document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML = '<audio id="source">' + mp3Source + oggSource + embedSource + '</audio>';
        }


    </script>



  </head>

 <body>
    <!-- Will try to play bing.mp3 or bing.ogg (depends on browser compatibility) -->
    <button  id="btnplay" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ playSound(); }, 500);">Play</button>  
    <div id="sound"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no HTML element with id named `source`?

Comment: there is      document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML = '<audio id="source">' + mp3Source + oggSource + embedSource + '</audio>'; but dynamic creation

Comment: @mzedeler there is document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML = '<audio id="source">' + mp3Source + oggSource + embedSource + '</audio>'; but dynamic creation

Comment: `playsound` adds the `source` element _after_ its intended use in the `$document.ready` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `<audio id ="source">` before creating it. Move the content of playSound to the document.ready block (before `$('#source')[0].play();`), and the problem is solved (I hope...).
Sorry for my English if I made mistakes.

Comment: index(audio).html:17 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Comment: In some browsers (eg Firefox) you can play audio/video only in click event handlers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Comment: unfortunately not